# DialogFragment и Handler

Tags: android, dialogfragment

После изменения ориентации экрана диалог не закрывается.

Код активности

```
MainHandler handler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    handler = new MainHandler(this);
    findViewById(R.id.mainButton1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View p1)
            {
                new RunExec(handler, "Finish");
                showProgressDialog("Progress");
            }
        });
}

public void showProgressDialog(CharSequence title)
{
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putCharSequence("title", title);
    ProgressDialogFragment progressDialogFragment = new ProgressDialogFragment();
    progressDialogFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    progressDialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "progress");
}

public void dismissProgressDialog(Bundle bundle)
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), bundle.getCharSequence("title"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Fragment fr = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("progress");
    if (fr != null)
    {
        ProgressDialogFragment progressDialogFragment = (ProgressDialogFragment) fr;
        progressDialogFragment.dismiss();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    }
    // TODO: Implement this method
    super.onDestroy();
}

static class MainHandler extends Handler
{
    WeakReference <MainActivity> activity;

    public MainHandler(MainActivity activity)
    {
        this.activity = new WeakReference <MainActivity>(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        MainActivity mainActivity = activity.get();
        mainActivity.dismissProgressDialog(msg.getData());
        // TODO: Implement this method
        super.handleMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

Код фрагмента диалога

```
 public class ProgressDialogFragment extends DialogFragment
 {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    setCancelable(false);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    builder.setTitle(getArguments().getCharSequence("title"));
    builder.setView(LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.dialog_progressbar_view, null));
    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface p1, int p2)
            {
                dismiss();
            }
        });
    return builder.create();
}
}
```

Еще код для полной кантины

```
public class RunExec
{
public RunExec(final Handler handler, final CharSequence title)
{
    new Thread(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                Message mess = new Message().obtain();
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(5000); //Выполнение задачи
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {}
                bundle.putCharSequence("title", title);
                mess.setData(bundle);
                handler.sendMessage(mess);
            }
        }).start();
}
}
```

После изменения ориентации экрана получается null

```
Fragment fr = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("progress");
```

Как решить проблему закрытия этого диалога после изменения ориентации экрана?

Answer (score 0):

Метод showProgressDialog() лучше вынести в тело класса(читай активити в данном случае), чтобы он мог быть доступен для других частей активности, а именно для OnResume(). Попробуйте перенести код создания фрагмента в метод OnResume

```
protected void onResume(){
     super.onResume();
     showProgressDialog("progress");
}
```

Да, и поправьте OnDestroy, сначала вызов суперкласса, затем уже действия

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    if (handler != null){
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    }
 }
```

Comment: В showProgressDialog(CharSequence title) значение и они могу быть разные, как в onResume() поместить?

Comment: Вызывайте свой метод с разными параметрами, в чем собственно трудность? Поправил немножко ответ.

Comment: Там тогда два экземпляра диалога получается. Один в public void onClick(View p1)
            {
                new RunExec(handler, "Finish");
                showProgressDialog("Progress");
            } второй в onResume()